# Need to replace ip addresses with different values in a single line

Tags: python, automation

I need to replace `ip ospf db area <IP4ADDR> ex <IP4ADDR> rtr <IP4ADDR>`

with `ip ospf db area 0.0.0.1 ex 0.0.0.0 rtr 222.0.0.1`.

I tried following, but it is not fulfilling the requirement.

```
>>> str = "ip ospf db area <IP4ADDR> ex <IP4ADDR> rtr <IP4ADDR>"
>>> newstr = str.replace("<IP4ADDR>","0.0.0.1")
>>> newstr
'ip ospf db area 0.0.0.1 ex 0.0.0.1 rtr 0.0.0.1'
```

For desired result, all 3 IP Addresses are to be replaced with different values. Can someone help me out if there is any functionality available in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function to `re.sub` that returns a different replacement string each time.  For example:

```
import re

s = "ip opf db area <IP4ADDR> ex <IP4ADDR> rtr <IP4ADDR>"
replacements = iter(['0.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0', '222.0.0.1'])
newstr = re.sub(r'<IP4ADDR>', lambda m: next(replacements), s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an *optional* argument `count`. According to Python Docs:

> ...If the optional argument `count` is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

So you can make a *chained call* (which will work because `replace()` returns the modified string):

```
new_str = some_str.replace("<IP4ADDR>", "0.0.0.1", 1)\
    .replace("<IP4ADDR>", "0.0.0.0", 1)\
    .replace("<IP4ADDR>", "222.0.0.1", 1)
```

**Note:** This is almost the same as doing:

```
new_str = some_str.replace("<IP4ADDR>", "0.0.0.1", 1)
new_str = new_str.replace("<IP4ADDR>", "0.0.0.0", 1)
new_str = new_str.replace("<IP4ADDR>", "222.0.0.1", 1)
```